# Передача типа в параметы метода C#

Tags: c#

Можно ли как-нибудь передать тип в метод?

```
 public void блабла( object type)
 {
     list<type> NewList = new list<type>() ;
 }
```

Что-то вроде этого?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void блабла<T>()
{
    List<T> NewList = new List<T>() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще то каждый object имеет метод Object.GetType() который возвращает тип этого объекта.

Но старайтесь использовать строгую типизацию, а именно принимать в методах конктретный тип, а не object.

Comment: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type' 

list< type.GetType> - Ругается...

Comment: @Varyag988 а зачем его запихивать в list? GetType возвращает Type - это информация о типе а не сам тип.

Comment: Ну и я к тому же. А я хотел бы что бы туда вставлялся тип. т.к. этот метод(с листом который) использутся для разных типов.. Ну я немного по другому решил проблему спасибо..

Comment: Используете отображение.

Comment: Понятно предельно...

Comment: var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstatce(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type))

Answer (score -1):

Используйте всю мощь [шаблонов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: Эээ.. Товарищ ХэшКод, вы зачем исправили моё сообщение? К тому же не правильно.

Comment: @AndrewFrolov На данном сервисе, пользователи, общаются на русском языке. Если Ваше сообщение исправлено не верно, Вы можете его отредактировать.

Comment: Да он часто так...