# Можно ли передать тип переменной в универсальный метод? (C#)

Tags: c#, типы, методы

Итак, допустим у нас есть следующий код:

```
public abstract class Letters
{
    //Код...
}
public class A : Letters { }
public class B : Letters { }
public class C : Letters { }

class Program
{
    public static void Method<T>() where T : Letters
    {
        //Код...
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Допустим, мы не контролируем, какой именно тип сюда попадает, но он точно относится к иерархии класса Letters.
        Letters obj = new A();

        Type type = obj.GetType();

        Method<type>(); //???
    }

}
```

Есть ли хоть какой то вариант передать тип переменной obj в универсальный метод, или это не допустимо, ну а если можно, то как?

*Да, я видел похожий вопрос [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11874/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-c), но он не решает мою проблему.*

Comment: а если вычленить нужный интерфейс?

Comment: перефразирую, вам нужно в метод передать определенные поля или определенные методы?

Comment: еще одно уточнение, а зачем (для чего) вам передавать в метод тип?

Comment: Вызывайте как `Method<Letter>();`. Если поведение метода зависит от типа переданного в него наследника, то, скорее всего, вы что-то делаете неправильно

Comment: Я так понял вам просто нужен тип переданной в метод переменной? Так `typeof(T)` чем плох?

Comment: Сколько лет программирую (оглаживаю седую бороду), столько лет встречаю на разных форумах подобные вопросы. И всегда автор вопроса не может объяснить, зачем это понадобилось. В ответ на уточняющие вопросы раздаётся лишь невнятное мычание и бормотание... В общем, как уже сказано, вы что-то делаете неправильно.

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. В цитируемом вопросе есть и `.GetType()` (для решения проблемы "в лоб") и обобщение. Тогда чего конкретно хочется или если уж непонятно чего именно хочется - то для какой задачи понадобилось?

Comment: Возможно, вы ищете для вашей проблемы неправильное решение. Опишите вашу настоящую проблему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно через рефлексию

```
typeof(Program)
    .GetMethod(nameof(Method))
    .MakeGenericMethod(type)
    .Invoke(obj : null, parameters : null);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли хоть какой то вариант передать тип переменной obj в
>   универсальный метод, или это не допустимо, ну а если можно, то как?

Если вы правильно сформулировали свой вопрос, то передать тип переменной `obj` в метод можно в качестве параметра типа `Type`:

```
public static void Method<T>(Type type) where T : Letters
{
    //Код...
}
```

И вызывать метод так:

```
Method<Letters>(obj.GetType());
```

Я не знаю, зачем это нужно. Я почти уверен, что вы не этого хотите. Но ИМХО, ответ на ваш вопрос дан.

Answer (score -1):

Почитал комментарии поразили ответы "бородатых" зачем, давайте может я попробую переформулировать Ваш вопрос.

Допустим мы создали две модели в SqlEntity

```
public class Cars 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Number { get; set; }
} 
public class Users 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FIO { get; set; }
}
```

Модели разные, но операции с ними одни и те-же, приходим к мысли что стоит их обобщить, переписываем.

```
 public abstract class Generic
 {
    public abstract int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string Name { get; }
 }
 public class Users : Generic
 {
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public override string Name => this.FIO;
 }

 public class Cars : Generic
 {
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public override string Name => this.Number;
 }
```

Отлично задача решена

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
         foreach (var item in new List<Generic>() { ... })
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
```

Далее мы свободно работаем с объектом не вникая какого он типа всё супер!

Далее идем в БД чтоб сохранить.

```
 new Repository<Generic>().Update(item);
 public class Repository<T> where T: Generic
 {
     public void Update(T item)
     {
         **тут мы будем посланы), для БД нет такой модели Generic**
         context.Entry(T).State = EntityState.Modified;
         **Автор логично предположил что решение должно быть таким, но увы**
         Type type = item.GetType();
         context.Entry(type).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
  }
```

Можно написать так

```
public void Update(T item)
 {
     if (typeof(Cars) == typeof(T))
           context.Entry(Cars).State = EntityState.Modified;
      else
           context.Entry(Users).State = EntityState.Modified;
 }
```

Но согласитесь это костыль.
Есть более элегантные решения?